# Dependency injection with Global.asax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am using dependency injection for the inject interface with the classes

I use it in the `Global.asax` like this

```
  new UnityContainer().RegisterType<IBookingService, BookingService>()
```

and controller

```
IBookingService bookingService
```

Now the thing is I want to change the injected implementation class for an interface in the controller level

How can I do it with a controller level?

i want to do some things like this in controller level

```
private readonly IBookingService bookingService;

if(countryCode = SE ){

bookingService = new bookingSE();

}

else IF (countryCode = NO ){

bookingService = new bookingNO();

}
```

i want to use Dependency injection for this

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you use the [Unity.Mvc NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc/3.5.1404). This will add a `App_Start\UnityConfig.cs` file to your project and you can add the registrations in its `RegisterTypes` method as follows:

```cs
container.RegisterType<IBookingService, BookingService>();
```

Perhaps you are already doing this, but I wanted to make sure since your exact code example with the `new UnityContainer().RegisterType` will not work.

Another interesting thing that this package does can be viewed in the `App_Start\UnityWebActivator.cs` file:

```cs
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
```

This line will register the unity container as standard MVC DependencyResolver. This allows constructor injection to be applied to your controllers. With this you can define your controller as follows:

```cs
public class MyCoolController : Controller
{
    private readonly IBookingService bookingService;

    public MyCoolController(IBookingService bookingService)
    {
        this.bookingService = bookingService
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // your usual MVC stuff here.
    }
}
```

In almost all cases, the use of constructor injection is advised over all forms of injection so stick with constructor injection unless there is no other way. And if you think there's no other way, please to ask here at Stackoverflow. We might be able to give some feedback on your code and design.

Comment: thnx u for the reply 
i want to do some things like this in controller level

private readonly IBookingService bookingService;

if(countryCode = SE ){

bookingService = new bookingSE();

}

else IF (countryCode = NO ){

bookingService = new bookingNO();

}

Answer (score 0):

Just call `Resolve`

```
var bookingService= container.Resolve<IBookingService>()
```

Comment: No, don't call `Resolve` from within your controller. That's a [bad idea](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/). Just use constructor injection.